# How to prevent intent of startCommand to return null when the app closed

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-service

I am using a service in my app. The service is used to show notifications. I send extras to the service when I start it. The problem is that when I remove the application window from the background the onStartCommand method is called again with a null intent so the extras become not exist. So my question is how can I stop the sticky service? Is it possible or no?

Comment: Check if the Intent has extras and ignore it if it doesn't?

Comment: This is an intended behavior when you return `START_STICKY`. Check documentation of possible return values of [`onStartCommand`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand(android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int)) to alter that behavior.

Comment: I know that but I need to find a way to stop it

Answer (score 0):

You can stop Stiky service by Calling `stopService(intent_of_your_service)` at onPause() or onDestroy() of your service. 
Here, intent_of_your_service is the Intent you created at onCreate(), or Use `stopSelf()`  (i.e., it stops the service) for stop sticky service.